# How do I change nuget source priority in UI

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In the nuget packages sources are some up and down arrows.

I can see from this question [Default package source for Nuget defaulting to newly added source and not All or nuget.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663822/default-package-source-for-nuget-defaulting-to-newly-added-source-and-not-all-or/47667693#47667693) that this is the priority.

But whenever I press up or down arrow and OK then when I go into the dialog again my sources keeps the old priority.

Does anyone know why it keeps the old direction, is it a hard block somewhere? The arrows does not work in my VS2017 nor VS2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that sources appear in the config file, or in the UI, have no affect on how NuGet uses those sources. I'm not sure about NuGet version 1 and 2 (used in Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013), but since NuGet 3 (Visual Studio 2015) at least, NuGet searches all file feeds first, and if none contain the package, or no file feeds are configured, then makes requests to all http feeds in parallel. When 2 or more sources contain the same package, the first source to respond is used. The order of sources in config files makes no difference. There is no such concept as source priority.

These arrow buttons have been confusing for years, and the team is planning on removing them: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8315

Comment: You sound convincing so I'll accept that there is no answer. Thanks